# Can someone explain to be what I am supposed to do in these questions (simplifying boolean algebra)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm reading Digital Design by M. Morris Mano and I am solving the exercises. I got stumped in some of the questions.

[image]

In this one I am not sure how to do b). To get F I did the SOP using the truth table. Then I took the complement of the SOP(which if I am not wrong is done by negating it and then applying Morgan's Law). However the SOP is just y. The complement is then not y? So the minterms of the complement are the maxterms of the original function?

[image]

How do I solve this? I'm thinking about using Karnaugh maps to get the expressions and then taking the complements and using a truth table? Is that what I am supposed to do?

[image]

This one doesn't make sense to me. What if all the minterms are zero? I'm not sure what I am supposed to do.

[image]

Is it possible to do this one without Karnaugh maps?

[image]

[image]

What's the inhibition operation?

Comment: You don't see "inhibition" gates commonly discussed because, well... because there are arguments about what it means in boolean logic. (You can witness these debates on Wiki discussion pages.) You do see this concept in probability and set theory often. For example, in set theory the inhibition of A/B would mean "A intersection not B" -- or, put in regular words, everything in A that is also not found in B.Given the assertion that the operation isn't associative or commutative, I don't think it is about logic but about set theory. All logic debates I've seen suggest a gate that is one or both.

Comment: That said, feel free to visit [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/inhibit-gate/) and also, more abstractly, [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/ra/c5ra10085b#!divAbstract). Other than that, I'll leave this discussion for others. I've seen too many debates among electronics folks discussing logic gates to want to get involved (at this time.) That is, with respect to your last question, anyway. The rest is just plain too many questions. So again I'm leaving it alone.